# Sql Injection - Is the following open to attack?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, security, stored-procedures

I've recently started working at a company that was wide open to SQL injection attacks. As in they had next to no input sanitation at all.

After pointing out the problem, I've been tasked with fixing it.

Usually this would be rather easy, replacing bare variables with SQLParamater objects. 
However I've found some slightly strange code usage that got me wondering.

It seems that my predecessor had been using both stored procedures and some SQL residing in code. However in one place he seems to be combining the two.

He is dynamically building SQL using some bare variables and then passing this generated SQL to a stored procedure as a parameter.

I was wondering about the security of this, would passing actual SQL through as a parameter sanitize it or will I have to re-engineer the stored procedure?

Here is a (vastly simplified) snippet of what he was doing:

```
DataSet ExecuteQuery(string unsanitizedInput)
{
    string dynamicSQL = "WHERE column = " + unsanitizedInput;
    MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter("param1", dynamicSQL);
    string procname = "StoredProc_Name";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(procname, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["string"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    return(ds);
}
```

Obviously the actual query is far more complicated with many parameters. But this should give you the principal of what what he was doing.

My question is this: Is the above secure? 
Does the unsanitized input get sanitized even when part of a far larger SQL statement that is to be injected into a stored procedure?

I know that the above is terrible practice and makes for some nigh impossible to figure out SQL queries but this is where I am right now.

All advice is appriciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends upon input i.e. if input is (1 or 1 =1) then yes it is open to attack. Where clause will be bypassed.

Comment: I think the best way is use parameterised queries.And validate the input before process as a query.If we can found sometypes of sql injection statements then avoid that input.

Comment: You haven't shown the stored proc, but I would assume that if dynamic SQL is being passed to it then the proc is building a query with code then executing it (eg. [EXECUTE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188332.aspx) in T-SQL). In that case it would still be subject to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, He is using "EXECUTE" after dynamically building the query, the SQL he is passing as a parameter is generally a whole load of conditional clauses that have been dynamically generated in code. I would post the full query but it is about 1000 lines long, because I'm pretty sure my predecessor lacked in sanity. I suppose this means I should rewrite it securely. Thanks again for the comments guys, if you post an answer I'll mark in correct...

Comment: As you can not pass a `WHERE` clause as parameter, my answer to the question is: No, it is neither secure nor does it work properly. The *only* way this can work is that the SQL statement is string concatenated within the stored procedure and then executed using `exec` or whatever. And that's the worst you can do.

Comment: The WHERE keyword is actually in the sproc, the parameter is a load of dynamically generated AND or OR clauses. Yes he is concatenating the string in the stored procedure. _And that's the worst you can do_. I don't know, there is some pretty messed up code in this project. I'd lay bets that there are worse dragons hiding in there... But then again I'm an optimist.

Answer (score -1):

Query with parameters not provide a full protection against slq injection attacks, neither store procedures. I used both, but in 2010 by site's db was seriously harmed by [two-step sql injection](http://blog.strictly-software.com/2009/10/two-stage-sql-injection-attack.html).

MSDN strongly recommends to check any input text for suspicious elements. See more [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

I used the following simple code to detect the sql injection (constructed using some good sources I already cannot recall):

```
public static bool DetectSqlInjection(string Text)
{
    string CleanText = Text.ToUpper().Replace("/**/", " ").Replace("+", " ").Replace("  ", " ");

    string[] InjectionPatterns = { 
                                     "VARCHAR", 
                                     "EXEC", 
                                     "DECLARE", 
                                     "SELECT *", 
                                     "SELECT PASSWORD", 
                                     "SELECT USERNAME", 
                                     "$_GET",
                                     "NULL OR",
                                     "UNION ALL SELECT",
                                     "WAITFOR DELAY",
                                     "SELECT pg_sleep",
                                     "SHOW TABLES FROM"
                                     };

    foreach (string Pattern in InjectionPatterns)
    {
        if (CleanText.Contains(Pattern))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are recommending a guideline for .NET 2.0 from May 2005? Todays recommendation is using parameterization as provided by prepared statements.

Comment: The more things change, the more they stay the same. Regarding the sql injection attacks, an only change since 2005 is that their attacks became more comprehensive and difficult to recognition. I also believed in parametrization until 2010, when I understood that parametrization is not a panacea though a really unpleased experience.